# Write and read data with swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am saving data on the device with this code

```
let url = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
print(fileURL)
try data?.write(to: url)
```

And I am trying to read it with this code

```
let url = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource:url , withExtension: nil) {
```

But I  am not sure on how to create the URL before reading the data. I get an error telling me that `Bundle.main.url(forResource:` is waiting for a String not an URL

Comment: You have to pass `if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource:url.lastPathComponent.deletingPathExtension() , withExtension: url.pathExtension)`

Comment: @vadian Why? The file is in the Document folder, not the app bundle.

Comment: @rmaddy I was just explaining why *Bundle.main.url(forResource: is waiting for a String not an URL*, no less no more. I have no clue how the bundle is involved in the workflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the contents of the file to a variable of type `Data`, you can use the initializer of `Data` accepting a `URL` as its only input parameter.

`Bundle.main.url(forResource:url , withExtension: nil)` can be used to access a file that is part of your application bundle. However, in your previous line you are giving the URL in the documents directory, so it seems your file isn't actually part of your application bundle, so you shouldn't use that line of code.

```
do {
    let url = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
} catch {
    print("Error: cannot read file")
}
```

Comment: "part of your application bundle" so things can be placed outside of application bundle? Is there any technical term for that? Do you mean like an image I download from internet? Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: Bundles are not exactly the same thing as directories. Have a look at the [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i) for more information.